# Probability of Results for 3 person golf round

Tags: probability

I'm trying to determine the probability of each result for a 3 person golf round. I want to determine the probability of each player either winning or tying for the winning score.  I've created a spreadsheet with 500 results to back into the solution, but am more confused than when i started.
Here are my givens:

P1 beats P2: 39.2%

P1 beats P3: 40.4%

P2 beats P1: 41.6%

P2 beats P3: 40.6%

P3 beats P1: 38.8%

P3 beats P2: 40.0%

P1 ties P2: 19.2%

P1 ties P3: 20.8%

P2 ties P3: 19.4%

Actual Results:

P1 beats P2 & P3: 23.4%

P2 beats P1 & P3: 25.4%

P3 beats P1 and P2: 23.0%

P1 and P2 tie and beat P3: 8.2%

P1 and P3 tie and beat P2: 8.2%

P2 and P3 tie and beat P1: 6.8%

All 3 tie: 5.0%

At first, I thought these were independent events, so probability of Player 1 beating player 2 and 3 would be P(P1 beats P2) * P(P1 beats P3), or .392*.404=.158 (15.8%), but the actual results show the answer to be 23.4%.  What am I missing?

Comment: For example, the events "$P_1$ beats $P_2$", "$P_2$ beats $P_3$", "$P_3$ beats $P_1$" are certainly not independent - they cannot happen together. More directly, "$P_1$ beats $P_2$" suggests that $P_1$ has a good day and *by that* is more likely to beat $P_3$ as well.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Agreed. I should have mentioned that for my original purposes, all three did not play together to get the percentages of times each won.  i.e. player 1 played player 2 200 times and won x%, player 2 played player 3 200 times and won y%, and player 1 played player 3 and won z%.  I'm trying to determine probability if all three played.  but, I get where you're coming from.  any suggestions on what I should look into? I'm a developer and math isn't my strong suit.

Comment: It seems like you really need the probabilities of what each player scores.  It's more believable that the scores are independent.  Are these data available?

Comment: @saulspatz The scores are technically available, but there are many other factors that go into the score (i.e. par, wind, course difficulty).  What i'm trying to do is say how many times did player 1 play the same course on the same day as player 2. who won more? How many times did player 1 play the same course on the same day as player 3? How did that break down? Same goes for 2 and 3.  I could grab all times all three played same course same day, but I'd end up with a smaller sample size. Was hoping i could get probabilities with the information I had.

Comment: Even with what you've done, you have the problem with the conditions.  Perhaps Player 2 plays better than Player 1 in the wind, but is more likely to flag on a hot day.  I don't know if there's a good solution.  You might try grabbing all the data when they played the same course on the same day, and seeing how the sample size actually is.

Comment: @saulspatz To be clear, I created a spreadsheet that had 3 columns (one for each player) and randomly generated a number between 1 and 5 for each column to represent their score. Then I caclulated each of the givens based on the results of those columns. Both the "Givens" and the "Actual Results" are technically "Actual Results" based on the spreadsheet I created.  I'm trying to figure out how I could have Calculated the "Actual Results".

Comment: @saulspatz See spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M97JNpTd8N5iRTCARayzIwM1luDAlZQ5cppDDUyJwEE/edit?usp=sharing